# SQL Query - Set column1 with values from column2 based on the value of column3

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I want to update column1 with values from column2 based the value of column3. This is what I have:

`UPDATE Table
SET Column1=Column2
WHERE Column3='Value'`

Is this possible?

**EDIT** I tried this, but I didn't get the results I wanted (as in, none of my rows changed). I didn't get any errors though.

**UPDATE** Figured out my error. Answer is below.

Comment: If you just had tried it then you'd know it works.

Comment: That's the exact syntax you want, yes.

Comment: oops, sorry. I forgot to mention that I did try it but it didn't work for me. there were no errors though, so that's what's confusing me. I'll edit my post

Comment: @mc1234436457 And are you sure that you have rows in your table where `Column3 = 'Value'`?. What happens if you just do: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column3 = 'Value'`?

Comment: @Lamak Yep. Sorry, I just figured out what I did wrong. The value of Column3 has the same name as Column2, so it was the order of my query that messed everything up. This is what worked: `UPDATE Table SET Column2=Column1 WHERE Column3='Value'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, Okay. Now I see where I went wrong. The Value of Column3 has the same name as Column2, so I messed up the order. This is what worked:

`UPDATE Table SET Column2=Column1 WHERE Column3='Value'`